# How do I conditionally render a value field formik field?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web, formik

So I declared Field component in Formik

```
           <Field
              allowClear
              name="productId"
              label="Selected Product"
            />
```

This is a reusable component that I also use when I edit the fields, the "productId" name passed is from the backend, there is one value from the DB that I would like to conditionally check so that it won't render, I tried doing this

```
render={data => if(data.productId==='none') return ''}
```

But it just crashses, is there a way to conditionally check a value that is getting passed to Formik field?

Comment: Could you also share the crash log details?

Comment: @Josh it just shows a white screen. So I assume render is not a real setting I'm using    "formik": "^1.5.8",